How would you let a reader know of a long sentence intonation?
I'm not sure if this would go here or in writing.stackexchange.com it's related to writing but it's more of a general English language question.
After reading this question and the first answer I started thinking, many times I've started reading a long sentence as you would read normally only to find a question mark at the end, so by the time I notice I awkwardly switch to a question intonation going up like ⤴
In Spanish we use ¿ and ¡ so from the start you somewhat know how to read what's coming.
Is there something similar in English?
And more specifically to the question and answer linked.

"You made a mess," said John, sternly.

Is there a way to do something like that but before the spoken sentence? Like:

A stern voice sounded.
"You made a mess"

But that seems like it would get repetitive and even then would only work on specific cases/scenarios.
PS: Forgive my tags, I have no idea how to tag this.

Does Spanish have a way of indicating a stern voice via punctuation?

Not that I know

If you're specifically interested in sternness, I'm not sure there's much to be added to the linked questions: you can use speech tags, adverbs, or descriptive text, which can come before the speech. If writing fiction you should try and make the dialog seem stern through word choice and expressions used, especially if it's a long sentence. Italics or capitals might look weird (especially for the whole sentence) but certainly can add emphasis in some contexts. This does seem more suited for Writing SE, as it's about writing techniques.

What is wrong with "John said sternly, 'you made a mess'"? Similarly, if you have a question you can use "John asked "where are you going with that thing?" You can do similar things for exclamation marks: "John said excitedly, "I found it!"  or "John screamed "Watch out ... it's going to bite!"

I'm not specifically interested in sternness, that's just the example I got from the linked question/answer, I was asking a more general question, even without ¿ and ¡ I could expect a question if I started reading How would or similar, so in relation to opening marks I wanted to know if you could also turn around the "sentence" speaker said structure. @PeterShor I don't know if it's wrong, maybe I'm just used to the "sentence" speaker said structure so the other way around does sound weird to me.

For a question, only the last few syllables (or even just the last one) are subject to a raised iintonation, so putting a question mark at the end doesn't seem a problem. Generally, word order is also different (VSO not SVO) so there may be an early indication that it's a question.

While "sentence", speaker said is more common in English, lots of authors use it the other way around sometimes, often for exactly these reasons. Is "sentence", speaker said the proper way to do it in Spanish?

@PeterShor You'd nearly always use inversion for Sentence, said speaker in the Spanish version.

I'm confused. The first part of your question talks about sentence intonation of questions and how some sentences when written are ambiguous (could be a statement or could be a question). But then the example you give has nothing whatsoever to do with questions or intonation. Did you mean to ask about the intonation of saying something sternly (among many possible manners of speaking)? And if there is a punctuation mark that tells this in writing?

@Mitch it's a question about showing intent or where a sentences should be read (as a question, as if whispering, as if screaming, etc...) with 2 different cases, questions and exclamations which in Spanish are easy to read even if the sentences is long or split in 2 lines and the one related to the writing question I linked.

Long sentences are usually suboptimal in style anyway. A long interrogative sentence (ed David Lu's here on Quora can usually (and usually should) be broken down into smaller sentences.

@Daviid OK, so you're asking if there is a way to signal what the intonation (or more generally some emotional nuance) to a sentence -before- the sentence is uttered/appears? 1) do what Peter Shore suggested, put the manner before the sentence, or 2) don't worry about it, authors often put the nuance afterwards and the reader readjusts in their heads or rereads the sentence.

One big diff: Though in English, we typically use the question word ‘does’ or ‘do’ to frame our questions, this is different in Spanish. [https://www.mezzoguild.com/learn/spanish/grammar/interrogatives/]

I can only read this sentence all at once: “You made a mess,” said John, sternly. If I were reading it aloud to, say, a child, I would already be speaking in a stern voice before I uttered the dialog tag, because I already saw what was coming.
